# How to output smooth cspline curve as a data file

Tags: output, gnuplot, smoothing

Does anybody know how to extract some data of smooth cspline curve for a given data?

For instance, there is a data file which has 2 columns corresponding to x and y values. I can draw the data with smooth cpline curve by the following commands

```
p 'data' w lp, ""  smooth csplines
```

I want to extract the smooth cpline curve as an another data file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done by setting a `table`. Consider the following data file:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 2
4 2
5 4
6 8
7 5
8 3
9 1
```

The data itself and its `csplines` interpolation look like this:

[image]

To print the interpolation to a table one does the following:

```
set samples 100
set table "table_100"
plot "data" smooth csplines
set samples 20
set table "table_20"
plot "data" smooth csplines
unset table
```

`set samples` determines the number of points used to construct the spline curve. And you can visualize it:

```
set key left
plot "data" pt 7 t "Original data", \
     "table_100" w l t "Splines (100 samples)", \
     "table_20" w l t "Splines (20 samples)"
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Use `set table 'temp.dat'` to redirect the plotted data points to an external file

```
set table 'temp.dat'
plot 'myfile.dat' using 1:2 smooth cspline
unset table
```

To test it

```
plot 'myfile.dat' using 1:2 with points title 'original points',\
     'temp.dat' using 1:2 with lines title 'smoothed curve'
```

Comment: Bad synchronization :-D I was writing my answer when you posted this. It's impossible to beat you!

Comment: @Miguel :) Sorry, I think I should step back a bit to not disperse most of the other answerers... Nice, that you added some examples to your answer. I had been looking for a duplicate question, but didn't find an appropriate one. Now we have your answer as nice reference

Comment: Well, at least with the gnuplot tag one has a chance to answer. Have a try at being the first to answer a python question...

Comment: Does anyone know how to overlap the "dot" and the "line" in the legend, so that I will get a single legend entry instead of two different entries for the same data?